# How to position the <span> in the center of an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the  in the middle of the image.

Should I use another div?

Tried "align-content: center !important;"

it did not work

```css
.africa-section {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    border: solid 1px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.africa {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.africa-section span {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="africa-section">
    <img src="images/giraffe1.jpg" class="africa">
    <span>Meet with Nature</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If the span is a caption for the image consider to use [figure and figcaption tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

Comment: Way better than I think! Thanks